# How to use non geographical maps in react native?

Tags: react-native, leaflet

Actually I want to use custom image as map in react native, so please share or suggest if anybody knows native library for non geographical maps with some example for react native.

Is this possible with "react-native-maps" ?

Comment: Try searching `Custom tiles`.

Comment: did you find a solution for react native?

Answer (score 0):

Try MapSVG, the link: [MapSvg](https://mapsvg.com/). 
It offers you a SVG map of every country in the world, and you can style it how you like it.

Comment: i need same features as  what the leaflet provides like clustering, custom image as map, move marker etc  , is that possible with MapSVG?